# How to Change the color of the text in donut chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts, donut-chart

How can I change the particular text color in donut chart

Example: `"10% Need Action"`, I need to change the `10%` to red color.

I have included the text inside donutchart.
I am trying to change the color of the text as mentioned above.

Here is my code

```
$(function () 
    {
        $('#dc-target-fill-rates').highcharts({
           chart: {
               type: 'pie',

                  },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButtons: {
                    enabled: false,
                    menuItems: null
                }
            },
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            floating: true,
            text: "<span><b>10%</b><br/>Need Action</span>",
            style: { color: '#60727d', fontSize: '15px', fontFamily: 'Avenir LT Std Light' },
            x: 0,
            y: -5
        },
        subtitle: {
            //text: '3D donut in Highcharts'
        },

        tooltip: {
            style: { fontFamily: 'Avenir LT Std Heavy' },
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)',
            borderColor: '#a9a9a9',
            headerFormat: "",
            pointFormat: '<span style="color: {point.color}">●</span><span style="color: {point.color}">  {point.name}</span> : <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                innerSize: '80%',
                //depth: 45,
                shadow: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Need Action',
                y: 5,
                color: '#fc5d45'
            }, {
                name: 'At Risk',
                y: 10,
                color: '#ffd52f'

            }, {
                name: 'On Track',
                y: 50,
                color: '#5db567'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: try to use class in span and give color.

Comment: Change the fill for the class `.highcharts-title tspan` like `.highcharts-title tspan{ fill:red` }. Refer https://jsfiddle.net/hrv3tfzs/

Answer (score 3):

Change the `fill` for the class `.highcharts-title tspan`. Refer https://jsfiddle.net/hrv3tfzs/

Add this style to your CSS

```
.highcharts-title tspan {
  fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response.

Comment: What's good about this solution is that it gets around the code swapping Highcharts does when rendering spans in the final SVG.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to what Pugazh suggested, you could do the following:

```
title: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true,
    text: "<span style='color: red; font: 15px Arial;'><b>10%</b><br/>Need Action</span>"
    x: 0,
    y: -5, 
    useHTML: true
},
```

If you use the `useHTML` attribute, you can add simple markup to your title text. The Highcharts span tags are notorious for swapping out values when the chart is rendered as an SVG, which is why I added the styles as inline code vs. the `style` attribute in your original code.

Just be mindful of your quotes here and escape any additional single or double quotes you need to use.